# Rails App Assets Not Being Loaded on Development Environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rack, nomethoderror, activesupport, rails-assets

Every time I spin up my Rails App locally, none of the CSS shows up. The debugger in the browser shows a `get` request for all of the asset files with fingerprinting, but they all fail since the files can't be found. Here is what one of those requests looks like:

`GET http://localhost:3000/assets/announcements.self-e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855.css?body=1`

In the Rails Server Console, I get a Rack App Error, as well as a `NoMethodError` for the `undefined method 'Silence'`. Here is what one of those errors looks like:

`2017-01-08 17:24:49 -0800: Rack app error handling request { GET /assets/normalize.self-cadbbf81015902777c37852b3ea54398335fd421c6c76891c077ec5954211bb4.css }`

`NoMethodError: undefined method 'silence' for #<Logger:0x007fe1062c1c78`

Both Error logs (Browser Console and Localhost Server Console) contain multiple renditions of the same error, all pointing to Assets (*.js, and *.css).

I have searched through countless StackOverflow Posts but to no avail. This also for some reason only affects this one application; all my other Rails applications run fine. Here are my specifications:

Rails Version: `5.0.1`

Ruby Version: `2.3.1p112`

Things I have tried:

`assets:clean`, `assets:precompile`, `rm -rf /tmp` and `/public/assets` directpories, all of the previous prepended with the development environment, recloning the repository from github and bundle installing.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old question, but stumbled across this while trying to fix the same problem.

I found as well as Ryan Bigg's answer I needed to comment out the following line in `development.rb` to stop Sprockets from bombing in Rails 5.2.2:

```rb
  # Suppress logger output for asset requests.
  # config.assets.quiet = true
```

Comment: Yep. This solved it for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're running into this issue: https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails/issues/376.

Where you've made this configuration change you should be using `ActiveSupport::Logger` instead. Where you have `Logger.new`, use `ActiveSupport::Logger` instead.

Comment: Are you saying to replace instances of ```Logger.new``` with ```ActiveSupport::Logger```? If so, there are no instances of ```Logger.new``` in my development.rb file. My issue does seem to match that from which you've linked, but I can't seem to find a solution within there.

Answer (score -1):

check The Sprockets 4 Manifest in rails 5

http://eileencodes.com/posts/the-sprockets-4-manifest/

It might help you.